# Installing pgfcore.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, installing, miktex, pgf-core

There is a problem with installing `pgfcore.sty` file for the `beamer` package. This file can not be installed from the internet (TeX says file not found) and when I plug this file manually into the directory, the TeX does not find the file. This all is done in Windows.

Comment: Are you using MiKTeX? If you do so, you probably have to update the FNDB.

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint. yes, i am using miktex...but i dont know what is FNDB, is it a package?

Comment: use `initexmf --update-fndb` in a command prompt

Comment: The Alex tip really works.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend to install or to update the complete `pgf` package.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error in Debian Buster

```
 sudo apt install texlive-pictures
```

where the following package resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.

Comment: This solved the issue for me too (on Debian 11)!
Thank you! (:

Answer (score 1):

I successfully solved this problem by :

1. Clicking on Start.
2. Search for **MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin)** [This step is very important]

Note : Do NOT right click on **MiKTeX Package Manager** and select **Run as Administrator**.

3. Search for **pgf** package.
4. Right click and install that package.

Done. The error is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with *WinEdt* and *Windows 8.1* when I starting a new user profile in Windows.
When I was trying to compile a presentation in *Beamer*,
the same error was popping up.
Tracing the log file,
I saw that *WinEdt* was **not** able to download the package from the internet.
Then, I have installed *TeXStudio* and tried to compile.
It connected to internet and downloaded the necessary files,
and compiled correctly.
Then, I went back to *WinEdt* and tried to compile and it did work also.
I guess, *WinEdt* **cannot** take the administrative authentication to connect the internet unless you *run as Administrator*.
You can use the properties of the exe file to *run as Administrator* as default.